# U1partial file extension on Ubuntu One

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, windows-7

I synchronize Ubuntu one between my office (windows 7) and my home (Ubuntu 10.10), when I synchronize in windows 7 I can get my files with no problems from web or Ubuntu, but when trying to get them later (modified from Ubuntu) from windows they always make a u1partial file and doesn't delete the older one, I delete the u1partial extension and the file works, so the problem is that Ubuntu one doesn't replace the files.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might be due to the fact the Ubuntu One is still in Beta for Windows. Your problem looks similar to [this bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-windows-installer/+bug/689516).